# Minimal non solvable group is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

I suppose to prove in my homework that

> Every minimal non solvable group is simple.

I can't find the way. Thank you.

Comment: Please tell us what is your definition of "minimal non solvable group". You can do that by editing your question.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes a minimal non-$\mathfrak{X}$ group is defined as a group which is not $\mathfrak{X}$, but all of whose proper subgroups are $\mathfrak{X}$. (Here $\mathfrak{X}$ is a group-theoretic property like *solubility*.)

With this interpretation, the result is false. Take $G = \operatorname{SL}(2,5)$. Here $Z(G)$ has $2$ elements, and $G/Z(G) \cong A_{5}$. One can verify that all proper subgroups of $G$ are soluble,  the important step being possibly that $G$ does not split over $Z(G)$. This depends on the fact that the generator 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}
$$
of $Z(G)$ is the square of
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&2\\2&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

---

If you include in the definition the requirement that proper quotients are also in $\mathfrak{X}$, then Nicky Hekster's proof applies.

Comment: Andreas thanks, exactly my thoughts, since if it is only subgroups for minimality then the homework problem is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If $N$ is a proper non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$, then both $G/N$ and $N$ are solvable, whence $G$ is solvable, a contradiction.

Comment: This uses a slightly different definition of minimal than the one I would use (I would mean it in terms of subgroups rather than order).

Comment: For infinite $G$ the statement is not true - there is a vast literature on infinite minimal non-solvable groups. They do not have to be simple.