# Why $ G/\Phi(G) $ is a minimal simple group, where $ \Phi(G) $ is the Frattini subgroup of $ G $ ?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ be a minimal non-solvable group. Why  $ G/\Phi(G) $ is a minimal simple group, where $ \Phi(G) $ is the Frattini subgroup of $ G $ ?

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821545/minimal-non-solvable-group-is-simple) says that a minimal non-solvable group is simple (actually it depends on the definition). What is your definition of minimal non-solvable group and minimal simple group?

Comment: @Crostul But that question was wrong! As is proved in one of the answers, ${\rm SL}(2,5)$ is minimal non-solvable (i.e. all of its proper subgroups are solvable), but it is not simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $G/\Phi(G)$ is not simple, then let $N/\Phi(G)$ be a minimal normal subgroup. Then $N < G$, so $N$ is solvable. Let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$ not containing $N$ (such an $M$ must exist since $N$ is not contained in $\Phi(G)$). Then $MN=G$, and since $N$ is solvable but $G$ is not, $M$ cannot be solvable, contradicting $G$ being minimal non-solvable.

So $G/\Phi(G)$ is simple and is clearly minimal simple.